# centering image on a webpage

Tags: html, css

How can i make an image to appear in the center of a webpage the image should be floating so that it will be in ther center vertically as well as horizontally .. there a re lot of snippets but none of them is complete so its not f any use to me :( I have only one jpg in the webpage nothing else

this is what i tried, this aligns it  center horizontally but not centering it  vertically

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title> Welcome </title>
  <style type="text/css">
  .centeredImage
    {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    padding:0px;

    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<p class="centeredImage">
<img  src="mypic.jpg" alt="welcome " width ="1024" height = " 565" >
</p>
```

-T

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a background image?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very tricky situation that's been discussed here more times than I can imagine.

Some would say use javascript to measure the window and move the image manually.

But if you don't know JS and really want to use vertical-align, try this: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<img src="mypic.jpg" alt="Welcome" class="centered" />
```

CSS:

```
.centered {
    width: 1024px; height: 565px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; top: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px; /* 1024 / 2 */
    margin-top: -283px;  /* 565 / 2 */
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtvyp/

Just for clarity's sake: I removed the <p> tags for centering, as they have no semantic value (i.e., they are not describing a paragraph).

Instead, we're using absolute positioning to put the picture at the halfway point of the window (its container). That, however, puts the *top-left corner* at that position. To actually center it, we use the defined dimensions of the picture and re-position it using negative margins of half the original size.

Hope that helps.